# Consulta de registro con hash

Tags: php

les tengo una pregunta, es que yo estoy haciendo un registro de iniciar sesión con hash pero cuando ya entra al sistema puede consultar los usuarios, las contraseña y el empleado a la cual le pertenece el registro pero cuando lo hago en vez de aparecerme la contraseña normal me parece el hash entonces como haría para que me aparezca la contraseña normal (Pero manteniendo el hash)

Comment: no te va a aparecer la contraseña normal; es decir la que ingresó el usuario; por que ya desde que se hizo el alta paso la misma por un proceso de hash

Comment: Si amigo pero al tenerlo como hash hay posibilidad que por medio de una consulta yo me pueda traer la pass pero sin el hash, es decir aparte que ya esta encriptada yo la quiero ver en un registro de consulta

Comment: hasta donde se eso ya no se puede, pues la cadena de texto quedó modificada desde el momento que la registraste

Comment: Eso mismo pensé entonces muchas gracias por tu aclaraciones amigo